# Tensorflow: split tensor of unknown size into chunks of given size

Tags: python, tensorflow, split

I would like to split a tensor into multiple sub-tensors of equal or near-equal size. Since I don't know the size of the tensor beforehand the splitting into even-sized chunks is not always guaranteed. However, `tf.split` seems to expect an even splitting and can therefore fail sometimes!

In numpy, there is `np.split`, which also raises an exception if the array cannot be divided into evenly sized chunks. To avoid this issue, one can use `np.array_split`, which allows a last chunk of a different size. This is exactly the behavior I am looking for in tensorflow.

**Summarized: What is the best way in tensorflow to split a tensor into multiple chunks if I don't now the size of the tensor but only the desired chunk size? Is there a similar function to `np.array_split` which I have not found yet?**

Answer (score 0):

To answer

> Summarized: What is the best way in tensorflow to split a tensor into
> multiple chunks if I don't now the size of the tensor but only the
> desired chunk size?

I'm not aware of a built in Tensorflow function. In Eager execution you can convert the tensor to numpy array using `tensor.numpy()`. In graph mode you can return the results in a RaggedTensor

```
@tf.function
def split_with_reminder(x, max_size):
  # Reshape the tensor without the reminder.
  length = tf.shape(x)[0]
  l = length - length % max_size
  dense = tf.reshape(x[:l], [l // max_size, max_size])
  dense = tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(dense)
  if l == length:
    return dense

  # If there is a reminder add it
  reminder = tf.reshape(x[l:], [1, -1])
  return tf.concat([dense, reminder], axis=0)
```

outputs

```
split_with_reminder(tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 2)
# [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
split_with_reminder(tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 3)
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
split_with_reminder(tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 5)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
split_with_reminder(tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 6)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Note that your mention of np.array_split is not accurate, because:

- It takes the number of chunks and not the "desired change size".
- It allows more than a single "last chunk of a different size".